# Comparing Multiple BYTE values

Tags: c++, comparison

I'm programming an online game, so I'm confused a little bit about multiple comparison, I need to make it best way, that's why I'm asking here.

Here is my code:

```
bool CHARACTER::UseItemNewAttribute(TItemPos source_pos, TItemPos target_pos, BYTE bType0, BYTE bType1, BYTE bType2, BYTE bType3)
{
    LPITEM item;
    LPITEM item_target;

    if (!IsValidItemPosition(source_pos) || !(item = GetItem(source_pos)))
        return false;

    if (!IsValidItemPosition(target_pos) || !(item_target = GetItem(target_pos)))
        return false;

    if (bType0 <= 0 || bType0 > 255)
        return false;

    if (bType1 <= 0 || bType1 > 255)
        return false;

    if (bType2 <= 0 || bType2 > 255)
        return false;

    if (bType3 <= 0 || bType3 > 255)
        return false;

    if (!item_target->AddNewStyleAttribute(bType0, bType1, bType2, bType3))
        return false;
...
```

First is: Here, I can check that BYTE (0, 255) values but these are looks like really crap code. as I know... What is the best way to do that? (I want to make it from best way to keeping best performance.)

Second is: I need to make comparison for each value, [!type0 == type1], [!type0 == type2] .... like that. Each value should be one in that case. What is the best way to do that?

Comment: There is no answer, interesting...

Comment: isn't BYTE an unsigned char? If so, there's no need to check <= 0 and > 255

Comment: But, how can I check is same or not with other BYTE values? There is a crap way to do that, but I don't want to do it. I need a proper way..

Comment: With std:valarray, you can do it matlab-style. `(byteArray1 == byteArray2).sum()>0`, which I think isn't less crapy.

Comment: Hmm anyway, thanks, I'm waiting for another answers....

Comment: are you sure bType{0;2;3;4} cannot be == 0 in your logic ?

Comment: 0,1,2,3 can not be == 0 and can not be same ..

Answer (score 0):

Alright, after hours I found a good way to do that. std::unique and std::resize works well...

Here is an example:

```
std::vector<BYTE> vec_bTypes;

vec_bTypes.push_back(11);
vec_bTypes.push_back(11); // duplicate!!!
vec_bTypes.push_back(12);
vec_bTypes.push_back(13);

std::vector<BYTE>::iterator it;

it = std::unique (vec_bTypes.begin(), vec_bTypes.end());
vec_bTypes.resize( std::distance(vec_bTypes.begin(), it) );

// output will be 11 12 13...
```